# Return values based on LINQ query C# for multiple tables

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core

Table 1: Main

Table 2: SubMain

Table 3: jnMainSubMain

Main table records

| MainId | MainContent | isRemoved |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello | false |
| 2 | Hii | false |

SubMain table records

| SubMainId | SearchId | isRemoved |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | false |
| 2 | 456 | false |

jnMainSubMain table records

| jnMainSubMainId | MainId | SubMainId | isRemoved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | false |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | false |

LINQ Expression

```
var searchId = input;
IQueryable<Main> query = this._Context.Main;
query = query.Include(h => h.jnMainSubMain)
    .Include("jnMainSubMain.SubMain")
    .Where(x => !x.isRemoved);

result = query.Where(x => x.jnMainSubMain.ANY(y => y.isRemoved == false && y.SubMain.SearchId.Equals(searchId)));
var result = query.ToList();
```

Input given: 123

Expected Result: jnMainSubMain table should have only 1 record as follows

Main table records

| MainId | MainContent | isRemoved |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello | false |

SubMain table records

| SubMainId | SearchId | isRemoved |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | false |

jnMainSubMain table records

| jnMainSubMainId | MainId | SubMainId | isRemoved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | false |

But because of ANY LINQ expression, I am getting 2 records (jnMainSubMainId: 1, 2) as the result.
I cannot use ALL Linq expression because I am getting zero records in jnMainSubMain table.

Please let me know if there is any LINQ expression that can return only 1 record for the jnMainSubMain table. But I want the LINQ to have IQueryrable for Main table.

Comment: 1) look at ThenInclude to load data that is related to something you just Included. 2) know that Include and Where are different things - your Where might find one parent because some certain child exists, but Include will include all its children not jsut the one that existed in your search term, 3) starting from a different place may give you a different, easier query e.g. `db.jnMainSubMain.Include(j => j.Main).Include(j => j.SubMain).Where(j => j.SearchId == 123)` - gives you just the one jnmainsubmain row, together with its sole related parent from each table